# App_Browsers folder on an Azure web role

Tags: asp.net, azure, browser-detection

Solved: see EDIT

I have a .browser file in my App_Browsers folder that detects Firefox on Android. When I publish the site to an Azure web role (under a Cloud Service) my App_Browsers folder doesn't show up on the web role and the site will not detect Android Firefox correctly.

If I manually place this App_Browsers folder on the web role it works as expected and detects Android Firefox just fine.

What am I missing that is preventing this folder from being published to the web role correctly? I am using VS 2015 and MVC 4.5.

Thanks

EDIT: Found that the simple solution was that the .browser file inside the App_Browsers folder was not set with a build action and was not set to copy always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the simple solution was that the .browser file inside the App_Browsers folder was not set with a build action and was not set to copy always.